# Artifacts on screen google nexus 4 when loading settings

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, nexus-4

I have defined a settings functionality in my app, and it is working perfectly on every phone I have tried except for the Nexus 4. The screen it shows it is something like this when accessing to settings:

[image]

I think that this is related with the fact of using the camera on my app and the release of the resources, but since it did not happen to me in any other phone, I don't know how to approach the finding of this bug.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: did you check the logs for any interesting messages or exceptions?

Comment: SOLVED! The solution was to unable the hardware acceleration on the manifest on SettingsActivity. Now it seems to work fine. Thanks.